# Using Composer for PHP as a centralized Server

Tags: php, networking, composer-php, server, centralized

Here is the situation.

5 of the laptops share a same network.

So the query is with Composer for PHP.

I want to make my machine which will act as a centralized server for Composer only to the systems which are my network.

I am performing `composer install` or `composer update` from the regular composer server

And I want my native systems to point to my system and take the composer update.

I'm very bad at explaining, but I hope the query is understood well.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this? Or is it a private repository what you are searching for: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: The purpose is I don't want all of the systems to take an update from server.. As its time consuming..
Instead get Composer updated just in one machine and pass on that update to native systems..

All of the systems use Git for maintaining project files